# Open new tab with mouse weel and onclick event

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick, tags

To open a link in a new tab

```
<a href="mypage.php" target="_blank">My text</a>
```

Using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function openLink(){
    window.location = 'my_page.php';
 }
</script>

<span onclick="openLink()">My text</span>
```

How can I open the link in new tab using **CTRL+Click** or **click with Mouse Wheel** without using the "a" tag?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: without using which tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect `button` and `ctrlKey` properties of the event object and use in conditional

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
   console.log('CTRL key : ', evt.ctrlKey, '  Button : ',  evt.button);  
})
```

```html
<button>
Click me
</button>
```